# Find coefficients of polynomial

Tags: polynomials

I sometimes encounter a problem where I need to find coefficients of a polynomial given planar points, which lie on it. I usually plug the points in the polynomial and solve the equations.

I noticed that it is possible to construct the polynomial directly as a sum of polynomials, which have the property that if one plugs in a x-value then the first term gives the correct y-value, while all the other terms are zeros. For the next x-value the second term gives the correct y-value, while all the other terms give noughts again. And so on. The coefficients can be obtained by simply calculating all the multiplications and additions arduously.

Am I using a not so easy to prove -theorem implicitly?

Comment: that's [Interpolation by Lagrange's Polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial)

Comment: To be clear, are you looking for an exact polynomial solution, or will an approximate solution suffice?

Comment: Lagrange method is what I had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of problem comes under the category of **curve-fitting**, where we need to adjust given planar points to a required degree of polynomial.

The methods to find the polynomial comes under this category:

1. Graphical method
2. Method of least squares
3. Method of group averages
4. Methods of moments
   And so on..

I myself prefer Method of least squares since it makes the calculation easier.
( [method of least squares.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFitting.html) )

The method you are enquiring about may be the [**superposition principle**](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SuperpositionPrinciple.html) which is one of the common techniques used in calculation of electrical circuits parameters and have similar use in mathematics too.

Comment: If you need further help., don't hesitate to ask.